# Time difference in MySQL between state change

Tags: mysql

I have a table on which I have lights and their corresponding status:

```
timestamp           name    state
2019-03-07 11:16:32 Light_A 0
2019-03-07 12:36:32 Light_A 1
2019-03-07 13:15:12 Light_A 0
2019-03-08 02:11:45 Light_A 1
2019-03-08 02:18:45 Light_A 1
2019-03-08 02:22:45 Light_A 0
2019-03-18 03:14:45 Light_B 0
2019-03-18 03:16:45 Light_B 1
2019-03-18 03:18:45 Light_B 1
2019-03-18 03:20:45 Light_B 0
2019-03-19 17:20:12 Light_B 0
2019-03-19 17:22:12 Light_B 1
2019-03-19 17:23:12 Light_B 0
```

I would like to measure how many hours each light is turned on.

So far I got:

```
SELECT x.*, TIMEDIFF(MIN(y.timestamp),x.timestamp)diff 
FROM data x 
  JOIN data y 
    ON y.timestamp >= x.timestamp 
WHERE x.state = 1 AND y.state = 0
GROUP 
    BY x.timestamp;
```

Which works great except when two consecutive rows have the same State = 1

The command above returns:

```
timestamp           name    state   diff
2019-03-07 12:36:32 Light_A 1       00:38:40
2019-03-08 02:11:45 Light_A 1       00:11:00
2019-03-08 02:18:45 Light_A 1       00:04:00
2019-03-18 03:16:45 Light_B 1       00:04:00
2019-03-18 03:18:45 Light_B 1       00:02:00
2019-03-19 17:22:12 Light_B 1       00:01:00
```

While instead I would expect this result:

```
timestamp           name    state diff
2019-03-07 12:36:32 Light_A 1     00:38:40
2019-03-08 02:11:45 Light_A 1     00:11:00
2019-03-18 03:16:45 Light_B 1     00:04:00
2019-03-19 17:22:12 Light_B 1     00:01:00
```

Could you please help me?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: is there also a auto increment fiel ?

Comment: Not yet, but if this could help I could add an autoincrement "id" field.

Comment: Presumably, you left out the name bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must eliminate all the rows that do not contribute to the result, such as a row with `state = 1` after a row with `state = 1` and then get the row with `state = 0` to calculate the difference:

```
select 
  t.timestamp,
  t.name, 
  t.state
  timediff(coalesce(
    (select timestamp from tablename where state = 0 and timestamp = 
      (select min(timestamp) from tablename where timestamp > t.timestamp and state = 0)), now()), 
  t.timestamp) diff
from tablename t
where 
  t.state = 1 and coalesce((select state from tablename where timestamp = 
    (select max(timestamp) from tablename where timestamp < t.timestamp)), 0) = 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kShJdbGZaBCeCAk2ZPyiH8/1)
Results:

```
| timestamp           | name    | state | diff     |
| ------------------- | ------- | ----- | -------- |
| 2019-03-07 12:36:32 | Light_A | 1     | 00:38:40 |
| 2019-03-08 02:11:45 | Light_A | 1     | 00:11:00 |
| 2019-03-18 03:16:45 | Light_B | 1     | 00:04:00 |
| 2019-03-19 17:22:12 | Light_B | 1     | 00:01:00 |
```